# Optional id parameter in Pydantic model caused SQLAlchemy Session to build a query using two different ID parameters

Tags: sqlalchemy, pydantic

**Question**

I am not sure where `id_1` is coming from in the WHERE portion of this query:

```
[SQL: UPDATE posts_2 SET id=%(id)s, title=%(title)s, content=%(content)s, published=%(published)s WHERE posts_2.id = %(id_1)s]
```

**Background**

I have a model for a post:

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default="True", nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
                        server_default=text('now()'), nullable=False)
```

and I am trying to use an update method:

```
@app.put('/posts/{post_id}')
def update_post(post_id: int, post: Post, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    updated_post = db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.id == post_id)
    if updated_post == None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="Post Not Found.")
    updated_post.update(post.dict()) # Update post based from postman (see body for postman below)
    db.commit()
    return {"message": updated_post.first()}
```

This is the Body from the Postman request:

```
{
    "title": "updated title 5", 
    "content": "new content 5",
    "published": false
}
```

However I get an `Internal Server Error`. When logging out I noticed that the `updated_post` query uses `id` to set the id and `id_1` as for the WHERE statement:

```
[SQL: UPDATE posts_2 SET id=%(id)s, title=%(title)s, content=%(content)s, published=%(published)s WHERE posts_2.id = %(id_1)s]
```

and the parameters use and `id` and and `id_1`:

```
[parameters: {'id': None, 'title': 'updated title 5', 'content': 'new content 5', 'published': False, 'id_1': 5}]
```

This is what the table looks like in my data base (note there is no `id_1`):
[image]

I would like the query to use `id` instead of `id_1` but I am not sure why it is using `id_1` to start with.

Thank you for your time and any information you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay writing it out was like rubber ducking and I figured out the issue. I was Pydantic Model where the `id` was optional:

```
class Post(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool
    id: Optional[int]
```

I think since I am setting the `id` by default through postgres, having it as an optional parameter on the Pydantic model was forcing another id param. After I commented it out:

```
class Post(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool
    # id: Optional[int]
```

the query works and the content gets update as expected. This was the SQL query that got logged out after the change:

```
SELECT posts.id AS posts_id, posts.title AS posts_title, posts.content AS posts_content, posts.published AS posts_published, posts.created_at AS posts_created_at
FROM posts
WHERE posts.id = %(id_1)s
```